# const char* to LPCWSTR in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have faced a problem in Qt with error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'
when calling: OutputDebugString( "wtf!" );

In simple C++ project I've always been setting "Character Set" to "Not Set", but this time it doesn't work, the error keeps displaying all the time. I tried other possibilities like "Use multi-byte" but still no effect. What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to be sure what's going on, but the easy short-term fix would be to use: `OutputDebugString(L"wtf!");`.

Comment: yes that would work, but it makes situation harder when I have OutputDebugString( lua_tostring(state, -1) );

Comment: Yup -- another possibility would be to use `OutputDebugStringA` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when I use qDebug instead of OutputDebugString it works.